# number of partitioning an $n$-set into subsets of a particular size

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

We know that the number of ways that an $n$-set can be partitioned into $k$ non-empty subsets is given by the Stirling number of the second kind, *i.e.*,
$\left\{\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right\}$. Now, what's the number of ways that one may partition an $n$-set into $k$ subsets of sizes $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k$ when the order of the subsets does not matter?

Let's denote that number by $B_n(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$.
Obviously, $B_n(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$ is nonzero only when $n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_k=n$. Therefore, one may drop the subscript $n$ and show the described number by $B(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$. Does this number have a particular name in combinatorics?

The same question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3908301/number-of-ways-of-splitting-set-into-disjoint-subsets), but the answer given to that question is for the case that the order of subsets **is** important. Indeed, if the order of subsets is important then the number of ways that one may partition an $n$-set into subsets of size $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k$ is given by
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k\end{array}\right).$$

**Example 1:** $B(2,2)=3$ since the only partitions of the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ into subsets of size $2$ are
$$\big\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\big\},\quad\big\{\{a,c\},\{b,d\}\big\},\quad\text{and}\quad\big\{\{a,d\},\{b,c\}\big\}.$$
Note that $\left(\begin{array}{c}4\\2,2\end{array}\right)=6$.

**Example 2:** $B(2,3)=10$. Note that in this case, $B(2,3)=\left(\begin{array}{c}5\\2,3\end{array}\right)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talking about partitioning into sets of size $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k$, let us organize these in terms of their size and group same-sized numbers together.  Notation can get messy if I try to be particularly careful so I'll be handwavy and relabel this list $n_{a_1},n_{a_2},\dots,n_{a_\alpha},n_{b_1},n_{b_2},\dots,n_{b_\beta},\dots$ where each of the $n_{a_i}=n_{a_j}$ are all equal but $n_{a_i}\neq n_{b_j}$ and so on...  Recognize that each outcome you hope to count was counted $\alpha!\beta!\cdots$ times if we used multinomial coefficients, once for each different relabelings of the parts in the partition within each size-category.

So, the modified count is $$\binom{n}{n_{a_1},n_{a_2},\dots,n_{a_\alpha},n_{b_1},\dots,n_{b_\beta},\dots}\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha!\beta!\cdots}$$

Note, $\binom{4}{2,2}\cdot\frac{1}{2!}=3$ and $\binom{5}{2,3}\cdot\frac{1}{1!1!}=10$ etc...

Comment: Does this number have a name?

Comment: @CLAUDE not to my knowledge, but it is a relatively straightforward application of the Shepherd's Principle along with multinomial coefficients.  The shepherd's principle loosely states that if when counting a scenario we overcounted every outcome by a common amount, we can divide by that amount to correct the count.